# Custom component layout order

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I have a custom component which is overriding the onLayout method as follows:

```
@Override
    public void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        int[] location = new int[2];
        this.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        int x = location[0];
        int y = location[1];
        int w = this.getWidth();
        int h = y+(8*CELL_HEIGHT);

        updateMonthName();
        initCells();

        CELL_MARGIN_LEFT = 0;
        CELL_MARGIN_TOP = monthNameBounds.height();
        CELL_WIDTH = w / 7;

        setFrame(x, y, x+w, h);
        super.onLayout(true, x, y, w, h);
    }
```

However, when using this component in a linearlayout as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView above"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />

    <com.project.calenderview.CalendarView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView below"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

The layout is rendered such that the textview "TextView above" is first, "TextView below" is second and then my component which is expected to be in the middle between both.

Edit:
Here's also the onDraw:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // draw background
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //Draw month name
        canvas.drawText(monthName, (this.getWidth() / 2) - (monthNameBounds.width() / 2), monthNameBounds.height() + 10, monthNamePaint);

        //Draw arrows
        monthLeft.draw(canvas);
        monthRight.draw(canvas);

        // draw cells
        for(Cell[] week : mCells) {
            for(Cell day : week) {
                if(day == null) continue;
                day.draw(canvas);   
            }
        }

    }
```

What is it that am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the onLayout methods is passing `int left, int top, int right, int bottom` indicating where your view is supposed to draw, but apparently you're completely ignoring it. You muse use those values to layout it properly.

**edit:**

if you're not extending a ViewGroup you shouldn't be overriding `onLayout(bool, int, int, int, int)`

from the docs [View.onLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onLayout%28boolean,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29):

> Called from layout when this view should assign a size and position to
>   each of its children. Derived classes with children should override
>   this method and call layout on each of their children.

**Derived classes with children should override this method and call layout on each of their children**

The issue you're having on the final result is in some other part of your code.

Comment: top & bottom are exactly the same value = 47 which means that the height is zero... this is why i decided to calculate my own values. Any reason for that?

Comment: is your custom component extending ViewGroup or just View ?

Comment: I am extending ImageView to be more specific

Comment: Okay, by not overriding this method, the height of my component is still 0. Whats the problem here? The only way i could overcome this by using the setFrame of the ImageView with the calculated values. Is there any alternative?

Comment: can you show the code of your onDraw(Canvas) ? If it's not too big, or at least some relevant snippet

Comment: I really can't give you a direct answer, but I'll give you the approach I would use to debug it: delete the onLayout code (we establish it's not necessary). Comment out the onDraw() lines and put a simple `canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);` that's a start stepping back to simple check what/where ur view is drawing. You can also use `getWidth` and `getHeight` to see how big it is.